# Creating a Buffer with Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

[image]here is my question:

I am trying to create a list with all the previous values are stored. But at most, I am getting this kind of results. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: please provide blend file, so that i don't have to rebuild everything on my own...thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can append the average number to a list like this:

[image]

UPDATE: if i (hopefully) understood you right, you can do it like this:

[image]

your start values on frame 1:

[image]

here you see the newest values:

[image]

result for frame 7:

[image]

Comment: Ok, there is no problem with me to append the number on the list. Issue is each new frame the list resets itself. In order to apply the moving average function, i need previous input values as well. Let me give you a lil code snippet `sum([x[idx-2], x[idx-1], x[idx]]) / 3` as snippet shows `x[idx] # current float number`,  window 3, I need 2 previous value to average them not a constant.

Comment: so you want this? eg. start with 100, 40 then 70 then 55 then 62.5 ? example for 2 values, not for 3.... but did i understand your right?

Comment: Now, I did edit the question with most simple way that I can ask. I kind of get confused about using loop. For my prediction, it should store the values from  each frame but, in theory there is no difference between theory and practice, while practice there is. I could slice the list I did manage it but I can't store the values.

Comment: just use my storing and loading like i did with the expression node -> this saves the data, and will be available in the next frame -> all your "data" gets lost in the next frame...

Comment: yes i see, thanks, but I do not understand why you using object input? Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: the list must be saved somewhere - you can take whatever object you want. i took the default cube.